# OData empty object with PUT/PATCH

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, odata

When I am trying to send PUT or PATCH request with JSON in body I am getting object with default values.
Everything is fine with get requests. And PUT request is working if specify data as parameters in URL.
I am using .NET Core and Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData 7.5.0 NuGet package
The example:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class OdataModelConfigurations : IModelConfiguration
{
    public void Apply(ODataModelBuilder builder, ApiVersion apiVersion)
    {
        var product = builder.EntitySet<Product>("Products").EntityType;
        product.HasKey(p => p.Id);
        product.Property(p => p.Name);

    }
}

[ODataRoutePrefix("Products")]
public class ProductController : ODataController
{
 [ODataRoute]
 [HttpPut]
 [EnableQuery(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All)]
 public async Task<IActionResult> Put([FromBody] Product update)
 {
   // some code omitted
 }
}
```

I'v tried to use different body content and to add different headers (Specify OData-Version for example).
Here is one of body examples that I'v tried to use:

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://localhost:5001/odata/$metadata#Product",
"Name": "put tested",
"Id":"1"
}
```

Or another one:

```
{
 "@odata.type": "#ODataAPI.Models.Product",
 "Name@odata.type": "String",
 "Name": "patch tested"
}
```

Comment: Seems that it is related to the next one issue:
https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/issues/476

Comment: Did you registered the OdatamodelConfiguration?

Comment: Hi @Zinov, I think that it is taken by convention. Just because inherited from IModelConfiguration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything works like a charm without Versioning and Swagger. Even if I am just sending simple body:

```
{
 "Name": "put tested",
 "Id":1,
 "CategoryId":1
}
```

Was able to find next one project that shows how it is possible to combine OData and Swagger:
https://github.com/microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/tree/master/samples/aspnetcore/SwaggerODataSample